# Create metadata tables for Spring Batch in an embedded database

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I'm using Spring Boot autoconfigured Spring Batch setup with `@EnableBatchProcessing`. The problem is that it creates metadata tables in the main database and I don't want this behavior. I would like to save all the Spring Batch information to an embedded database.

I've tried using the `spring.batch.initialize-schema=embedded` property and adding H2 to the classpath, overriding `DefaultBatchConfigurer` bean with the H2 data source, replacing `JobRepository` and `JobLauncher` beans but it constantly creates metadata tables in the main Oracle database. I'm using Spring Batch 3.0.8 and Spring Boot 1.5.9.

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

**UPDATE**: Adding come configuration:

H2 config:

```
@Bean
public DataSource springBatchDataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.h2.Driver");
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:h2:mem:db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1");
    dataSource.setUsername("sa");
    dataSource.setPassword("sa");

    return dataSource;
}
```

Oracle:

```
@Bean
@Primary
public DataSource dataSource() throws SQLException {
    PoolDataSourceImpl dataSource = new PoolDataSourceImpl();
    dataSource.setConnectionFactoryClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("db.driverClassName"));
    dataSource.setURL(environment.getRequiredProperty("db.url"));
    dataSource.setUser(environment.getRequiredProperty("db.username"));
    dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("db.password"));
    dataSource.setFastConnectionFailoverEnabled(Boolean.valueOf(environment
            .getRequiredProperty("db.fast.connect.failover.enabled")));
    dataSource.setValidateConnectionOnBorrow(true);
    dataSource.setSQLForValidateConnection("SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL");
    dataSource.setONSConfiguration(environment.getRequiredProperty("db.ons.config"));
    dataSource.setInitialPoolSize(Integer.valueOf(environment.getRequiredProperty("db.initial.pool.size")));
    dataSource.setMinPoolSize(Integer.valueOf(environment.getRequiredProperty("db.min.pool.size")));
    dataSource.setMaxPoolSize(Integer.valueOf(environment.getRequiredProperty("db.max.pool.size")));
    dataSource.setAbandonedConnectionTimeout(120);
    dataSource.setInactiveConnectionTimeout(360);
    dataSource.setTimeToLiveConnectionTimeout(0);

    return dataSource;
}
```

Batch configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfigurer extends DefaultBatchConfigurer {

    @Override
    @Autowired
    public void setDataSource(@Qualifier("springBatchDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        super.setDataSource(dataSource);
    }

}
```

and some properties related..

```
spring:
  batch:
    job.enabled: false
```

Comment: You mean you overrode `DefaultBatchConfigurer#setDataSource(...)`?  How is the Oracle `DataSource` configured?  How is the H2 `DataSource` configured?  Please post the appliation.properties and/or the annotated code showing how the beans are created/named.

Comment: @Andrew S hey Andrew, thanks for the suggestion, yes, I've tried overriding both `setDataSource` and creating a bean of the type `DefaultBatchConfigurer`. Please, see the edits

Comment: Does @Qualifier work on an overridden method?  Maybe try debug and set a breakpoint to inspect the stack to see why _dataSource_ is being used instead of _springBatchDataSource_.  All else fails, maybe switch the bean names so H2 is _dataSource_.

Comment: @Andrew S works fine) seems like the issue in the initializer..

Answer (score 3):

1.redefine the **BasicBatchConfigurer**

2.in spring-boot-batch-starter, you must create your own **BatchDataSourceInitializer**, so it will execute the init sql scripts

```
@Configuration
public class MyBatchConfigurer {

    @Bean
    public BasicBatchConfigurer batchConfigurer(BatchProperties properties,
                @Qualifier("springBatchDataSource") DataSource dataSource,
                ObjectProvider<TransactionManagerCustomizers> transactionManagerCustomizers) {
            return new BasicBatchConfigurer(properties, dataSource,
                    transactionManagerCustomizers.getIfAvailable());
        }

    @Bean
    public BatchDataSourceInitializer batchDataSourceInitializer(@Qualifier("springBatchDataSource") DataSource dataSource,
            ResourceLoader resourceLoader, BatchProperties properties) {
        return new BatchDataSourceInitializer(dataSource, resourceLoader,
                properties);
    }
}
```

Comment: interesting.. however, it continues to create tables in the oracle database. I guess, I should redefine BatchDatabaseInitializer bean defined in BatchAutoConfiguration.. what do you think?

Comment: try to remove the **spring-boot-batch-starter** from your pom.xml, only need to add spring-batch-core-xxx.jar

Comment: BatchDatabaseInitializer is created by spring-boot-batch-stater

Comment: is there a class to create metadata tables in the embedded database just like BatchDatabaseInitializer?

Comment: i modify my answer, try it with including **spring-boot-batch-starter**

Comment: yeah, tried that. it should work but then it seems like I have to redefine all the beans I'm interested in from the autoconfiguration:c

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180282/discussion-between-clevertension-and-dmitry-senkovich).

Answer (score 0):

You need to qualify your H2 datasource bean

```
  @Bean(name = "springBatchDataSource")
    public DataSource springBatchDataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.h2.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:h2:mem:db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1");
        dataSource.setUsername("sa");
        dataSource.setPassword("sa");

        return dataSource;
    }
```

I hope this help.

Comment: by default a bean from the Java Config is named with the name of the method that creates it